# How to login with github oauth for react app

Tags: reactjs, github, oauth

How do I login with github oauth in my react project. Is there a sample project for this? After logging in, I need to see the user's repos.

Comment: Check this page : 

    https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps